# How to specify which version of jar to use for org.apache.commons.lang3.builder

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven, mule

I am trying to run a Java application for Akamai EdgeGrid Signer that I imported, but it complains **"JSON_STYLE cannot be resolved or is not a field"**, so I downloaded and imported the latest jar file for "org.apache.commons.lang3", which has "JSON_STYLE" (version 3.5):
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.5

Then I added this jar file to the Referrenceed Libraries of my project, but in the code it still complains **"JSON_STYLE cannot be resolved or is not a field"**. So it looks like it is still referring to the old "org.apache.commons.lang3".

Is there a way for the code to refer to the new jar file that I imported for "org.apache.commons.lang3"? I googled this problem but still could not figure out the fix...Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You are using Maven, why are you adding libraries manually through Eclipse? Don't do that, declare it in the POM.

Comment: I am using Mule Anypoint studio, which is Maven driven, I can see the declaration is in the pom file:                                                                           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
            </dependency>                                                                                     Is this the correct setting? Thank you!